# ¿Cómo crear modelos de laravel a partir de una base de datos existente en SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

Ya poseo una base de datos en [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) y quisiera crear los modelos para [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) a partir de las tablas que ya tengo en mi base de datos.

¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo?

Comment: ¿La base de datos en que motor está?

Comment: La base de datos esta en SQL Server

Comment: Reabro dado que hay una respuesta aceptada y votada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente extensión: [Model generator](https://github.com/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator).

#### Instalación (Composer):

Composer global:

```
$ composer require ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator --dev
```

Composer local:

```
$ php composer.phar require ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator --dev
```

#### Uso y ejecución:

Añades el proveedor (provider) `Laracasts\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider` a tu archivo `config/app.php`.

Ejecutas el siguiente comando desde tu terminal (estando en el proyecto):

```
$ php artisan make:models
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien tube el mismo problema pero descubrí que solo tienes que crear un modelo para cada tabla y manejarlo a traves de los controladores, estos videos me ayudaron bastante:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HANoD1NxhbY&list=PLvHC_bH_JxV1xCUEZuSyszWiBe5Cnq34Y

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Las respuestas que son básicamente un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque si el enlace se rompe, la respuesta deja de tener sentido. Sería ideal que añadieras una descripción de lo explicado en el enlace para que sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios. Te recomiendo leer [answer] y que completes el [tour] (y así ganar tu primera medalla)

Answer (score 0):

Con [mysql-workbench](/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench) (Licencia GNU) se puede realizar ingeniería inversa a una base de datos MySQL para obtener el diseño de la base de datos, lo mísmo con [enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect) a base de datos Oracle, para SQL Server intenta con Microsoft Office Visio Professional.

Más información: [Ingeniería Inversa a Base de Datos](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Aplicar-ingenier%C3%ADa-inversa-a-una-base-de-datos-existente-en-un-modelo-de-base-de-datos-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614).

Comment: MySQL Workbench es una gran herramienta, pero a lo que el refiere es un «scaffolding» de código (a lo que en Rails le llaman, generador de código _automagicamente_).

Comment: OK, tienes razon, no había entendido la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo encontré este generador y me ha servido bastante https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator, las instrucciones también están ahí y se explican mejor de lo que yo podría hacerlo, y si, jala los campos de la base de datos(aunque yo lo use con postgres) espero sea util.